# How can I send notification from user to user on onesignal?

Tags: android, onesignal

I use OneSignal to send notification from server and users to users.

In my app,users can send notification to eachother.

it is possible with `send tag`? if so how can i do that?

I do not want to use user ids. (How can find each user ids from another user?)

I want to do that like parse.com. One user setchannel and other user send notification to that channel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `sendTag` from the OneSignal SDK with your channel name as the key and `1` as the value.

You can then make a POST call to OneSignal's [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) REST API. Set the `tags` field according to the documentation page to target your 'channel'. This call needs to be made from your server since targeting `tags` requires your OneSignal App REST API key.

Comment: so a user can post call to create notification in app? is it safe to use REST API in app? thanks in advance

Comment: You should not use your OneSignal REST API Key in your app as it could be extracted from your app and used to spam your users. You can use the create notification REST API call in your app with `include_player_ids` as this does not require your app REST API key as other targeting parameters do. Otherwise if you need to target by tags you will need to make a call from your app to your device were you can safely use your REST API key.

Comment: thanks for answer, so you say , sending notification from app to app I should use  REST API call in your app with `include_player_ids` , so how can I find users ids from another user, Can I set the user id?

Comment: You will need to have your own server to handle the OneSignal player / user ids.

Comment: actually I have a server to collect data from users and I guess to have my own server to handle it but it is not the easiest way :)

Comment: link in above answer is not working, So I just want to post updated link here https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification